# Solving this simple(?) JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath, openhab, json-path-expression

I am new to this topic, but I hope you can help me. I can't figure out a correct JSON expression for solving my problem.

Given JSON structure (coming from zigbee2mqtt):

```
{
  "message" : "announce",
  "meta" : {
    "friendly_name" : "Lamp1"
  },
  "type" : "device_announced"
}
```

What I am trying:

`if $.type == 'device_announced' then return the friendly_name`

which in this case is

> `Lamp1`

Comment: What path have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for an expression like this:

```
$[?(@.type=='device_announced')].meta.friendly_name
```

So, we are filtering the root collection on `type`s equal to the search string, and then drill down to the friendly_name. You can test this online [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Note: Some implementations require you to wrap your JSON in an array `[ ]` to allow this kind of filtering.